# A way to handle parameters (configuration) in an app

Tags: ios, swift

I need to set some parameters (arrays of numbers) in Xcode to my app project. These parameters are to be loaded at compiling, not at the moment when app starts. I don't want to write them in a code, I think it'd be better to have some kind of separate file with configuration.

What is the proper way of handling this kind of configuration file for the app in swift? Or is it better to just put that configuration in a code?

Comment: You can use a plist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom `.plist` file, include it into the main app project, then reference it from the code. Example:

`myConfig.plist` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>testString</key>
    <string>Test</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

View Controller:

```
private lazy var config: [String: String] = parseConfig()

private func parseConfig() -> [String: String] {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myConfig", ofType: "plist"), let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: String] {
        return dict
    }
    return [:]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(config["testString"])
}
```

Output:

```
Optional("Test")
```